# Button_click event fired again without reason (Barcode reader involved)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im showing a Wizard upon click on a button in code behind.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Wizard myWizard = new Wizard();
     myWizard.ShowDialog();    
     if (myWizard.DialogResult != true)   
     {
         return;
     }
}
```

The wizard window is passed as a parameter in a command

```
void Switch2NextPage(object CallerWindow)
{
    WizardWindow = (System.Windows.Window)CallerWindow;
}
```

In the ViewModel of the wizard i'm trying to close the Dialog if in a textfield a specific text is entered.

```
public string OrderNr
{
    get
    {
        return _OrderNr;
    }
    set
    {
        _OrderNr = value;
        if (Orders.FirstOrDefault((order) => order.OrderNr == value) != null)
        {
            myNewOrder = Orders.FirstOrDefault((order) => order.OrderNr == value);
            WizardWindow.DialogResult = true;
            WizardWindow.Close();
        }
        myNewOrder.OrderNr = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("OrderNr");
    }
}
```

The dialog gets closed, somehow the click-event of the button is fired again.

Callstack shows only "external code" and the clickhandler.

I have no idea how to handle this.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: May be you confirm the text by pressing Enter, which on close of the window will push the button because it still has the focus. This is only a guess, though. Hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: Nope. The text is entered by a barcode reader. No keyboard involved...
Text binding like this: `Text="{Binding OrderNr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`

Comment: Based on some condition, if possible, you can at least exit out of the second click event.

Comment: Your view should not open any dialog windows directly. This is a bad approach that violates the MVVM concept and is hardly testable. There are two common approaches you can consider instead. One approach is to implement a service that can be used by the view model to display a new interaction window, thereby preserving its independence on the view's implementation. Another approach uses events raised by the view model to express the intent to display a new interaction view, along with components in the view that are bound to these events and that manage all the visual aspects.

Comment: Regarding the barcode reader: most of them send the linefeed or carriage return (or both) automatically.

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks a lot for the input about the barcode reader! Probably thats the point!
And also about the general MVVM concept. I'll try to do it better in a next project. This is my first WPF and MVVM project, coming from WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The involved barcode reader sent not only the code number, but also another CrLf (enter key).

This triggered the focused control (starting the Wizard) again after closing the wizard.

Thanks to @JeffRSon and @dymanoid